# jQuery selectors for dynamically generated HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

In my page, I use this block of code to generate [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML):

```
$.ajax({
        url: '...'
}).done(function (model) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= model.numberOfPages; i++) {
        html += '<a class="page_number" href="javascript:void(0);">'+i+'</a>&nbsp;';
    }
    $(".page_numbers").html(html);
});
```

But when I try to add a click event on these a tags, nothing happen. Where did I go wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $('.page_number').click(function (event) {
        //Some code here
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '.page_number', function(event) { ... });`

Comment: Is that code run before the items are generated?  Then you can't use basic `click` you need to use `on`.

Comment: @Hogan yes, it is, after use  on() it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind the events after you have added the elements to the page.

Or you can use a delegate instead, then you bind it to the parent element and specify which child elements it applies to:

```
$('.page_numbers').on("click", ".page_number", function (event) {
  //some code here
});
```

For jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.6.x you use the [`delegate` method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('.page_numbers').delegate(".page_number", "click", function (event) {
  //some code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, this is the is the way you bind an event to dynamically created objects

```
$(document).ready(function (event)
{
    $(document).on("click", ".page_number", function(e)
    {
       //some code here
    });
});
```

API Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/